# How to detect 'Idle' status in Mac (Java application)

Tags: java, macos

I have a Java application for Win & Mac where I need to know if the user is in an 'idle' status (no user interaction in X minutes).

In Windows I am using GetLastInputInfo and it is working perfectly:

```java
....

// Get the last input event info.
     
        public static int getIdleTimeMillisWin32() {
            User32.LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new User32.LASTINPUTINFO();
            User32.INSTANCE.GetLastInputInfo(lastInputInfo);
            return Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime;
        }

....
```

For Mac I have read that CGEventSourceCounterForEventType could help me. But I can not find how to use it in a Java method

I would thank any help,

Hari

Comment: For what university course / assignment / programming test / job interview do you need that functionality? This is the 10th question like this in the last couple of days.

Comment: No this is not an assignment. This is the task i need to do it. If you know the solution means, let me know. Thanks!